# Get rid of the "twig" and "template" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

With now more than 2 month in beta, this Stack Exchange site has over 750 questions. Let's subtract all the questions which are tagged "plugin-development" (there are 130 of them) and we have 620 questions left.

One should think that most of these questions are at least somehow related to templating and thereby to Craft's templating language Twig. I can't prove it, but I'm rather sure that out of these 620 questions, this should apply to a minimum of 400 of them.

But we've only this amount of questions tagged:

[twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twig) × 78
[template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) × 65

Yep, nearly no one uses them (me neither)!

So what's the purpose of having these at all? Is it possible to remove (and/or forbid) them? Should we encourage everyone to use them (and possibly make them synonyms)?

Answer (score 2):

I see your point, but I would argue that they're *underutilized*—not *insignificant*. I'm not sure whether there should be a distinction between [twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twig) and [template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template), but templating questions are certainly prevalent and important. I think removing and/or forbidding would be getting rid of useful taxonomy, so encouraging appropriate use would be ideal.

tl;dr
**Keep them, encourage consistent usage.**

Comment: How would you define appropriate use of these tags if one can only add max. 5 tags to a question? I hope you get me right, I don't want them to be removed, I just don't know if I'm doing it right to never include them.

Comment: Slightly off topic: could you rename the "ranges" tag to "range" for me, please. Used the plural by accident. And one more request: did you see that "date" to "datetime" tag synonym I added?

Comment: It might be a good idea to make [tag:twig] a synonym of [tag:template], but I should probably test out that idea by reviewing questions first. Sure, I can change "range"—and I'm pretty sure I consolidated "date"/"datetime" back when you added the synonym.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Combining "twig" and "template" would definitely make it easier for us to spend one of the 5 available slots for such a non-spezific tag. I'd vote for "twig" becoming a synonym of "template" and not via versa, because templating questions could (in very rare occasions) have nothing to do with twig. Discuss this and, if you decide to combine them, mark this here as "status-completed" :)

Comment: I agree 100% with Matt here, they are definitely _underutilized_ and not _insignificant_. Making "twig" redirect to "template" works for me... All Twig things are templates, but not all templates are Twig things. (FTR, I think 5 tag slots is a lot!)

Comment: Sorry for the "date"/"datetime" confusion, Matt. They are indeed synonyms already. One thing that's strange though is that you can still make use of both (and people still use them in combination)! What's the purpose of configuring synonyms then – I think I didn't get that in it's entirety.

Comment: @Lindsey yes you're right, 5 tag slots is really not a small amount. But if you add "twig", "template", "elementcriteriamodel" and "filter", there's only one slot left to describe your *actual* problem! But consolidating them is probably the way to go. Btw. does "filter" work as a synonym for "elementcriteriamodel" (probably not. damn!)?

Comment: @carlcs Synonyms can be created as shortcuts to other tags, and optionally merged so that previous tags and histories are updated. I just added [tag:twig] as a synonym of [tag:template] and performed the merge. As a result, all [tag:twig] questions are now [tag:template] and if you attempt to use "twig" the tag popup will suggest "template" instead—even though you can override and still go with [tag:twig]. I think this one's done unless I failed to answer your question! Sorry this took me so long!